# Expectation of residuals in Zero Intercept Model

Tags: regression, residuals, conditional-expectation

We know that the summation of residuals in a regression through origin model is not necessarily 0. Does that imply that Expectation of Residuals is not necessarily 0? CLRM still holds, so should that imply that Expectation of residuals, despite the fact that summation of residuals is not 0, is 0?

Answer (score 1):

No. If the underlying regression model is correct then by definition the residuals will have expectation zero. Inclusion of an intercept term need not change this assumption.

For a model with no intercept term, minimizing the sum of squared deviations is not generally equivalent to minimizing the absolute value of the sum of residuals. This can be checked by repeated sampling experiments on a computer. If you simulate a large number of samples and fit a regression model to each sample, you will see that the sum of residuals is on average zero.